# Convergence of the derivatives implies convergence of the original functions on $1$-dimension.

Tags: measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, absolute-continuity

Let $f_n, f \in W^{1,p}([0,1])$ for some fixed $p \in (1,\infty)$ and all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. By modification on null sets, we may then assume that $f_n, f \in C[0,1]$.

Now, if $f_n(0)=f(0)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f_n' \to f'$ in $L^p[0,1]$, is it necessarily true that
\begin{equation}
f_n \to f \text{ in } W^{1,p}[0,1] ?
\end{equation}

I strongly suspect so, but cannot find a way to justify this guess rigorously. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $f' \in L^p([0,1])$ implies that $f' \in L^1([0,1])$, hence $f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t) \ \mathrm{d} t$ is an absolutely continuous representative of $f$. Knowing this, we have by Hölder's inequality

$$
\begin{align*}
|f_n(x) - f(x)| &\le \int_0^x |f_n'(t) - f'(t)| \ \mathrm{d}t \\
&\le \int_0^1 |f_n'(t) - f'(t)| \ \mathrm{d}t \\
&\le \Vert f'_n - f' \Vert_{L^p}
\end{align*}
$$

So,
$$
\int_0^1 |f_n(x) - f(x)|^p \le \Vert f'_n - f' \Vert^p_{L^p} \to 0.
$$

Comment: Oops.. I was so dumb...Thank you...

Comment: Wait, I have a question. In the second term of your formula, is $L_p$ norm taken with respect to $x$ there? If so, how do you arrive at the final inequality? Could you provide more details?

Comment: @Keith I have re-written it. Hopefully it is clearer now.